# how do i use different fonts of the words a <p> paragraph ?? in css and html

Tags: html, css, fonts

[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2O2c.jpg)

how must I use different fonts in a paragraph? I attached an example in the above image?
I tried using

creative  corner

Comment: Have you considered using `<spans>` with different classes having different styles applied on them?

Comment: It sounds like you need to wrap the text you want to change in `<span>` tags. But please provide the code you have so far. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Instead of a paragraph you can use "span".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for completion, the comments pretty much answered it already.

HTML

```html
<p class="myTitle">creative <span class="myClass">corner</span></p>
```

CSS

```css
p.myTitle {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

p.myTitle .myClass {
 font-family: monospace;
}
```